# java: converting from List<SomeClass> to List<SomeInterface> when SomeClass implements SomeInterface

Tags: java, generics

I'm having a brain cramp: I have a `public interface SomeInterface` and a `static private class SomeClass` and am trying to return a `List<SomeInterface>` from one of my methods, but I get the error (on the `return list;` line below):

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<GenericList1.SomeClass> to
List<GenericList1.SomeInterface>
```

How can I fix this without having to create a new list?

**Clarification:** I do not want the list to be created as `List<SomeInterface>` (perhaps the obvious solution) because privately I want to maintain a `List<SomeClass>` to allow future access to SomeClass's methods beyond the ones in the public interface. This isn't shown in the example case below, but in my real program I need this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericList1 {

    public interface SomeInterface
    {
        public int getX();
    }

    private static class SomeClass implements SomeInterface
    {
        final private int x;
        @Override public int getX() {
            return this.x;
        }       
        public SomeClass(int x) { this.x = x; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SomeInterface> list = createList(10);
        printList(list);
    }

    private static void printList(List<SomeInterface> list) {
        for (SomeInterface si : list)
            System.out.println(si.getX());
    }

    private static List<SomeInterface> createList(int n) {
        List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            list.add(new SomeClass(i));
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should redefine your method as

```
private static List<? extends SomeInterface> createList(int n) { ...
```

and similarly, the other list declarations. This allows you to deal with generic lists polymorphically, **as long as you only read values from them**.

(Should you want to add new elements to a list, you should use `List<? super SomeInterface>` instead.)

This idiom is known by the abbreviation **PECS** - *Producer: Extends / Consumer: Super*, coined by Josh Bloch in Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 28.

As others have noted, this idiom is needed because a `List<SomeClass>` is **not** a `List<SomeInterface>`, even when `SomeClass implements SomeInterface`. The reason for this is thoroughly explained in the referred document.

Comment: ah, OK, this works. In my real program I'm returning a List<> wrapped by Collections.unmodifiableList() so they're going to be read only.

Comment: The answer had a link to Item 28 but the link is now dead.  A PDF of the book is available here:  https://github.com/ldfaiztt/CSE331/blob/master/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to popular belief, `List<Derived>` has absolutely no relation to `List<Base>`, even if `Derived extends Base`.

Just because the classes share a hierarchy doesn't mean that collections of them do. This is true for generics in general.

You could alter your code as follows:

```
private static List<SomeInterface> createList(int n) {
        List<SomeInterface> list = new ArrayList<SomeInterface>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            list.add(new SomeClass(i)); //add a SomeClass object - valid, because it has the interface
    return list;
}
```

Comment: yes, that's the obvious solution but I don't want to do that; see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the signatures of the methods like so:

```
private static void printList(List<? extends SomeInterface> list) {
    for (SomeInterface si : list)
        System.out.println(si.getX());
}

private static <T super SomeClass> List<T> createList(int n) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        list.add(new SomeClass(i));
    return list;
}
```

Using a wildcard in a return type is often a bad idea, because it forces you to use wildcards in all calling methods. I made createList a generic method so that the return type can be as flexable as possible while still being as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static List<SomeInterface> createList(int n) {
    List<SomeInterface> list = new ArrayList<SomeInterface>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        list.add(new SomeClass(i));
    return list;
}
```

Comment: that's the obvious solution but I don't want to do that; see my edits.