# Converting from Set<SomeEnum> to Set<? extends SomeInterface> when SomeEnum implements SomeInterface

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have an interface and an enum as follows:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    ......
}

public enum SomeEnum implements SomeInterface {
    ......
}

public class SomeClass {
    public void someMethod(Set<SomeInterface> s) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now to call `someMethod(Set<SomeInterface> s)` I create an enum set containing all of the elements, so I do following:

```
Set<? extends SomeInterface> choosen = EnumSet.allOf(SomeEnum.class);
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
obj.someMethod(choosen)
```

I get compile time error:

error: method someMethod in class SomeClass cannot be applied to given types;

```
required: Set<SomeInterface>
found: Set<CAP#1>
```

reason: actual argument `Set<CAP#1>` cannot be converted to `Set<SomeInterface>` by method invocation conversion
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends SomeInterface from capture of ? extends SomeInterface

**IMP:** I know that the error can be resolved by [changing the method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959000/1550811) to `someMethod(Set<? extends SomeInterface> s)`, but I CAN NOT change the signature of `someMethod`

Comment: Have you tried a cast? You should be able to cast one collection to another with @SuppressWarnings to keep the compiler quiet. Failing that, you should be able to cast to a Set<?>, then cast again.

Comment: Casting to `Set<?>` and then casting again to `Set<SomeInterface>` worked, thanks @The Thom. However `@SuppressWarnings` did not work.

Comment: I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Casting should really be the last resort, and is rarely really necessary. And **if** it is considered to be necessary, one should be aware that it destroys the type safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting and ignoring the warning are obviously not type safe. (It may be safe in this particular case, but I would not recommend it anyhow).

But the most appropriate solution also depends on what `someMethod` is going to do with the `Set<SomeInterface>`. If it is **only** going to **read** from the given set, then you can pass in an *unmodifiable view* on the set:

```
Set<? extends SomeInterface> set = ...
Set<SomeInterface> viewOnSet = Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
someMethod(viewOnSet);
```

This works because the `unmodifiableSet` view allows the returned view to be more specific: It is not possible to add new elements to this set, and thus, it is type-safe.

However, if the `someMethod` is going to modify the set, then you can use the approach that was already mentioned, namely creating a copy of the set with the desired type:

```
Set<? extends SomeInterface> set = ...
Set<SomeInterface> newSet = new LinkedHashSet<SomeInterface>(set);
someMethod(newSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast your Set to a `Set<?>` and then to the `Set<Whatever>` you want. This should resolve your issue...

Answer (score 0):

Got another way of achieving what I want is:

```
Set<SomeInterface> choosen = new HashSet<SomeInterface>(EnumSet.allOf(SomeEnum.class));
someMethod(choosen);
```

Similar to what McDowell metioned in `copyUp()` method.